# Eclipse throwing errors for deprecated methods

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install a project in eclipse, but it is throwing errors about deprecated methods.

Elipse preferences are like this:

```
java, compiler, errors/warnings, deprecated and restricted API, 

Deprecated API                                            Warning
    Signal use of deprecated API inside deprecated code  (unchecked)
    Signal overriding or implementing deprecated method  (unchecked)
Forbidden reference (access rules)                           Error
Discouraged reference (access rules)                     Warning
```

Are these correct settings? or is there anything that needs to be updated in pom??

Comment: Is it an error or just a warning? You can just ignore them if it's a warning.

Comment: nah, Deprecated API is just a warning-- the actual Error is from `Forbidden Reference`.

Comment: this is the error,  [ERROR] /path/FactoryTest.java:[21,14] [deprecation] /path/Factory in mypath.transform has been deprecated